# Pass Report Data Within a URL for SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, url, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a .Net Core web application, where some data is generated dynamically(Some mathematical calculations) and displayed on the screen.

When the user clicks "Print", we need to convert all the data displayed into a PDF.

Currently, we are storing the data in a DB and sending the PrimaryKey as a parameter to the SSRS report in the URL. And then SSRS calls another REST API to access that data.

Like described here - [Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-2016)

Is there any possibility for us to skip the Storing data in DB and directly pass the dataset to the SSRS server in a URL, and generate a PDF?

Comment: You can pass parameters within the URL. You can't pass datasets. Datasets come from the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can send only get variable to the reporting. And you can't send a lot of data because get variable has a restriction. If you have a lot of information save it in the DB and print is the best way, if not you can put the big string in get variable and parse in in the reporting